# Java - Create Zip-file with multiple files from different locations with subfolders

Tags: java, zip, subdirectory

I am trying to generate a zip file in Java, that contains several files of different types (e.g. images, fonts etc) that are lying in different locations. Furthermore I want the zip file to have subfolders where the files are put by their type (e.g. images should go to the images folder within the zip.

These are the files that I have (each can be in a different location):

- index.html
- img1.jpg
- img2.jpg
- font1.woff
- font2.woff
- style.css
- custom.js

And this is how they should be in the zip file:

- index.html
- images/img1.jpg
- images/img2.jpg
- fonts/font1.woff
- fonts/font2.woff
- js/custom.js
- css/styles.css

So far I have managed to take one file in a specific path and prompt the user for the output location. A zip-file will be generated with the file that is specified in the input. Here is the code I have so far:

```
JFrame parentFrame = new JFrame();

JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Speicherort auswählen");   

int userSelection = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(parentFrame);
String pathToFile;

if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File fileToSave = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    print(fileToSave.getAbsolutePath());
    pathToFile = fileToSave.getAbsolutePath();
}

pathToFile = pathToFile.replace("\\", "/");

String outFileName = pathToFile;
String inFileName = "C:/Users/asoares/Desktop/mobio_export_test/index.html";
ZipOutputStream zos = null; 
FileInputStream fis = null;

try {
    zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFileName));
    fis = new FileInputStream(inFileName);
    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(new File(inFileName).getName()));
    int len;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    while((len = fis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
        zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
} catch (IOException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
} finally { 
    if(fis != null){ 
        try { 
            fis.close(); 
        } catch (IOException e) {} 
    } 
    if(zos != null){ 
        try { 
            zos.closeEntry(); 
            zos.close(); 
        } catch (IOException e) {} 
    } 
}
```

I would be really glad if someone can help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

It should work like this.

The zip directory name should at best be created by another method (there are more image types than jpg :)).

```
public static Path zip(List<Path> files, Path zipFileTarget) throws IOException {
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFileTarget.toFile());
         ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos)) {
        if (!Files.exists(zipFileTarget))
            Files.createFile(zipFileTarget);
        createEntries(files, zos);
        zos.close();
        return zipFileTarget;
    }
}

private static List<String> createEntries(List<Path> files, ZipOutputStream zos) throws IOException {
    List<String> zippedFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher matcherFileExt = Pattern.compile("^.*\\.([^.]+)$").matcher("");
    for (Path f : files) {
        if (Files.isRegularFile(f)) {
            String fileName = f.getFileName().toString();
            String fileExt = matcherFileExt.reset(fileName).matches()
                    ? matcherFileExt.replaceAll("$1")
                    : "unknown";
            // You should determine the dir name with a more sophisticated
            // approach.
            String dir;
            if      (fileExt.equals("jpg")) dir = "images";
            else if (fileExt.equals("woff")) dir = "fonts";
            else    dir = fileExt;

            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(dir + "/" + fileName));
            Files.copy(f, zos);
            zippedFiles.add(fileName);
        }
    }
    return zippedFiles;
}
```

Edit: this approach works with java 1.7+. You can easily convert a `File` object to a `Path` object by calling its `toPath()` method.